# Map isn't centered on on the coordinates, Google Maps Javascript API V3

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, intel-xdk

I'm trying to make my first app/test on Intel XDK and start with a simple maps app.
My problem is when I try to center my map with the coords. 
The coordinates appear on right-top instead of center.
My code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
      //var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(-19.838817, -44.606980);
      var mapOptions = {
      center: { lat: -19.838491, lng: -44.606999},
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  }
//  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

My script is loaded on onload action of the tag body:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

My css file that define map size is mapa.css:

```
div#map-canvas{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks any help!

Comment: Where is the div with id="map-canvas"?  Does it have a size?  What does the CSS that applies to it look like?

Comment: Hello @geocodezip, the div with id="map-canvas" is inner the body tag.Look:
'<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>'

Edit: About the div size: Need I define the size of div that store the maps to show it centered? I ask its because the map appear in emulate tab, just your position is wrong. Thx for help!

Comment: @geocodezip I add a css file with #map-canvas sizes but anyway don't work.

Comment: Could you include that CSS in your question please.  Also any code required to do the tabbing.  (Searching this tag for your issue in tabs may find you a duplicate)

Comment: @geocodezip I edited with my css file and my tag body. I researched about my issue and found some similar questions, but nothing helped me. Some were using api v2, anothers were using markers, etc.

Comment: I made an observation:
When I reload the emulate tab on intel xdk some times the map is centered correctly.. and later.. it's a random behavior. Some idea?

Comment: It is probably a timing issue, sometimes the browser has finished rendering the div and it has the correct size before the map is initialized, sometimes the map is initialized before the browser finishes rendering the div for the map.

Comment: Your original code as posted above doesn't work in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj7j6eez/). If I add `html,body,` to the CSS definition, it displays on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj7j6eez/1/).  However, from your description, it is working sometimes on the intel-XDK, so that may not explain the actual problem.

Comment: Which device/OS are you having the issue on?  I'm on an iPhone 6/iOS 8 and my google maps apps are centering correctly.  Any chance you can put the full content up in a jsbin so I can try it in App Preview?

Comment: Hello @geocodezip and Ian Maffett, firstly thanks for your help!
I was testing my app just on emulate tab from xdk intel.
So I downloaded it to a galaxy y and for my surprise it worked!
So I believe that this problem is just a bug of renderization sequence of xdk intel. Thx for all... Have a nice 2015!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work.

**HTML**

```
<div id="canvas" style="height:300px;"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.838491, -44.606999),
       zoom: 14,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Please read the manual: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents

Comment: Thanx for your note, but I tried it too and don't work. I read the documentation and appear correct but don't work :S

Comment: I changed the code. Check this out. It works for me.

Comment: I tested it on a galaxy y phone.. and it worked without problem.. so I believe that it was a bug on renderization sequence on xdk Intel. Thx for your help! Have a nice 2015!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-19.838491, -44.606999),
```

Comment: Thx for your note, but I tried it too and dont work.

Comment: Does the initialize function work otherwise?  If you change other parameters in it, are those changes reflected? (Do you require a semicolon after the call to initialize() at the onload attribute?)

Comment: Hello @SpikeMF, thanks for your help... I tested it on a galaxy y phone and it worked without problems. So I believe that it was a bug of renderization sequence on xdk Intel. Thx for your help.. have a nice 2015!